# How to access non-default view inside view folder in code igniter

Tags: codeigniter, view

I know how to display default view in Code Igniter. But, how can I access other files inside view folder. Example I want to display '**application/views/admin/index.php**' but it isn't default view.

Comment: How did you go did you try my answer

Comment: I understand your answer. But I want when user access www.sample.com, he goes to User Page, then when user access www.sample.com/admin, he goes to Admin Page

Answer (score 0):

You can add sub folders in view like so.

```
$this->load->view('admin/index');
```

Is that what your meaning.

Codeigniter [Views](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html)

File name: Example.php

```
<?php

class Example extends CI_Controller {

   public function index() {
     $this->load->view('admin/index');
   }
}
```

Folder Structure

```
application
application / views /
application / views / admin
application / views / admin / index.php
```

I would not choose index.php for a name for a view I would rename it to another name dashboard.php or some thing. Because you have a index.php in the main directory.